# What does -f stand for in "php -f" when running a cron job?

Tags: php, linux, cron

What does the `"-f"` in 
say

```
* * * * * php -f myscript.php
```

stand for?

Comment: Do `man php` and answer yourself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the PHP Command-Line options reference: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php the `-f` option indicates which file the PHP engine should execute, in this case `myscript.php`.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that if you have only a single php script as the argument, `-f` does nothing.