# How do I express this cURL command in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, https

The command line curl is:

```
curl https://sitea.com/v1 -X PUT \
         -d callback_url="https://siteb.com/event" \
```

I have

```
ch = curl_init();

$callback_url = " https://sitea.com/v1";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $callback_url);

curl_exec($ch);
```

However, I am not sure about how to deal with the remaining options. What's -X, -d etc? and how do I express that curl command via PHP (not command line)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: "What's -X, -d etc?" --- how about some `man curl`?

Comment: Really? You don't know how to `man curl`?

Comment: @Mike Purcell: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12486686/251311 o_O

Comment: with 1012 rep i could imagine you would read manual before asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-X` specifies the command (HTTP verb) to use. In this case, its `PUT`. The equivalent would be `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');`

`-d` is the data (the payload) you want to send with the request. The equivalent would be `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'callback_url="https://siteb.com/event"');`

As others have mentioned in the comments, the first place to check "what does this option do" is the manual page (called the man page because `man` is the command used to load the documentation). If you do not have the curl utility installed, there are lots of websites that provide online search of Linux manual pages. One is http://man.he.net/

Comment: Thanks for being helpful! Will definitely heed your advice.