# php CLI mode -f flag

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I was reading about specifics of PHP in CLI mode and I can't explain for myself what utility has -f flag.

It's possible execute any php script as `"php name_of_script.php"`  or `"php -f name_of_script.php"`

I guess this option is just kind of syntactic sugar. Also its existence can be perhaps explained by the fact that it's more obvious for user when he sees -f that file is executed. I can't make up any other explanations. Do someone see any other usage of it?

Comment: From the manual: ["The -f is optional and may be omitted - providing just the filename to execute is sufficient"](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) - I guess it's a legacy parameter and may be deprecated in future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does -f stand for in "php -f" when running a cron job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486686/what-does-f-stand-for-in-php-f-when-running-a-cron-job)

Comment: I didn't mean specific case with cron. I got it. Thank you all. Perhaps I should be downvoted like that user too.

Comment: Cron or not, it's the same question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a very long history with a lot of the design decisions lost in the mists of time; I'm not sure anyone will be able to tell you for *certain* why there's both a `-f` option and the ability to run a file without any options at all.

However, it certainly seems designed for user convenience; most command line users would expect an interpreter to interpret a filename provided as a single parameter, and it's the most common use-case, so making it the quickest to type makes sense. My guess would be that the PHP CLI started off with *just* the `-f` option, and the option to run a file by providing just the filename was added later to make people's lives easier. The `-f` was retained for backwards compatibility.

I *can* think of one case where the `-f` option is useful: if the filename starts with a hyphen, for example `-.php`.

When provided as a single parameter, this will be treated as an option, and fail:

```
$ php -.php

Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
   php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
   php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code
...
```

However, with `-f`, it'll work:

```
$ php -f -.php
<script executes successfully>
```